# How do I work out the aspect ratio from the resolution by hand?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, divisibility, rational-numbers

For $1024 \times 768$ I can see that $768/1024 = 0.75$, i.e. $\frac34$, so $4:3$ makes sense. How do I do it for other resolutions like $1920 \times 1080$ though?

Comment: Factor the two numbers and remove common factors: $1920 / 1080 = 16/9$

Comment: @Winther Factorization is hard, but determine the greatest common divisor is easy and known since at least Euclid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is divide out the common factors until the two terms are coprime (unless they're the same to begin with, e.g., a square image). With your second example, I'd first divide out the 10, giving me 192:108, then I'd divide by 2, going to 96:54, and 48:27; then clearly you divide out the 3s, leading to 16:9.

I take it step-by-step like that because you said "by hand." With a computer, I'd just have it tell me $\gcd(1920, 1080)$, or better yet, have it express $\frac{1920}{1080}$ in lowest terms for me.

Comment: I would just like to mention that there is at least one aspect ratio which is not generally expressed in lowest terms, and that is 16:10. For example, by the procedure Bob suggests, a 1440:900 resolution would probably lead to 8:5, which is technically correct, but without passing through 16:10, which is of course of practical importance given how much 16:9 content is shown on 16:10 screens.